# How do I use export setu command

Tags: shell, path

What is the difference between `export` and `export setu` command? I have searched online these command (`export setu`) but it's not found.

Comment: what is setu? In what context would you use that? Is it short for setup? If yes setup of what?

Comment: I am trying to install one software.In this tools, the had mentioned first set, export setu=/home/telhinilmt/sampark so i don't know what is this? Actually i don't know shell scripting and also don't know path set method of shell file. so please tell me.

Comment: Please update your **question** with the relevant part of your comment, so it is more easy to for future visitors to follow the question without having to read through the comments. But note that your comments about (in)abilities regarding scripting, and pleading **don't belong in a question** (if needed you can put them in your profile text).

Answer (score 1):

`export` creates an [environmental variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) which can be inherited by [child processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_process).   For:

```
export setu=/home/telhinilmt/sampark
```

it creates the environmental variable named `setu` and gives it the value `/home/telhinilmt/sampark`.

`export` just by itself lists all of the shell's current environmental variables.